# Insert URL parameters into Javascript code

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I'm doing some conversion and revenue tracking using Virtual Website Optimizer. To track revenues, they instruct you to add a piece of Javascript code on the thank you page to determine the actual revenue earned.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _vis_opt_revenue = 0;
//zero should be replaced by the actual revenue figure
</script>
```

I'm using a Wufoo form and made it so that I can add a URL parameter that totals up their order, so for example if their order has a total of $280 they'll be sent to:

```
http://mysite.com/thank-you?total=280
```

I'm wondering: how can I make it so that URL parameter is inserted into the Javascript tracking code from Visual Website Optimizer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get query string values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Add this

```
function getParameterByName(name)
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
  var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
  if(results == null)
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Then change

```
var _vis_opt_revenue = 0;
```

to

```
var _vis_opt_revenue = getParameterByName("total");
```

Comment: Should should vote to close the question as duplicate if you can answer it with an existing answer. But I guess you know that...

Comment: @FelixKling hmm, I added content which the OP might not know (using the function).

Comment: Thanks, that helped. And yes, it was useful -- I didn't know how to use the function itself. Using 

     document.write 

it displays the parameter, so this might work.

Comment: this does look right. But is it the only way the value is passed over to the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var _vis_opt_revenue = 
         '$' + window.location.pathname.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```